# Fire and forget with java.util.concurrent

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, fire-and-forget

How to go about implementing a "*fire and forget*" behavior with java.util.concurrency? I tried:

```java
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

public void push(Callable<Boolean> task) {
    Future<Boolean> future = executor.submit(task);
    future.get(timeout, timeoutUnit);
}
```

but the `get()` is blocking until completion. The `push()` caller is not interested in the result of the task.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't call `get()`. `submit()` is enough to start the `Callable` in a `Thread`. You can pass around the `Future` and call its `get()` when you are ready to get the result (if ever).

The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.util.concurrent.Callable%29) states

> Submits a value-returning task for execution and returns a Future
>   representing the pending results of the task. The Future's get method
>   will return the task's result upon successful completion.
>
> If you would like to immediately block waiting for a task, you can use
>   constructions of the form result = exec.submit(aCallable).get();

So just don't call `get()`.

Comment: You're right, but I highlighted only half the story: my issue is that some tasks never end. I don't know how to go about framing the `submit()` with a timeout

Comment: @PhilippeBlayo That's not something that is possible with submit. If your task never ends, then the problem is in the `Callable`. If you need the thread to end, you can always try calling `cancel()` on the `Future`.

Comment: If you give small timeout, say 100ms, then it will throw TimeoutException, which you can catch and do a no-op to mimic fire and forget behavior.

Answer (score 6):

dont need the future object if you have to forget it i.e. dont care about the future of the thread. :)

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

public void push(Callable<Boolean> task) {
   executor.submit(task);
}
```

or if you need to use future some time later than :-

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

public void push(Callable<Boolean> task) {
   someCollection.add(executor.submit(task)); // use futures later
}
```

or just use execute from Executor and pass Runnable, if you dont intent to get the future at all.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

public void push(Runnable task) {
   executor.execute(task);
}
```

// execute will invoke default exceptional handler in case of exception, that can be lost in case if you dont get hold of futures in submit method.